# return a searched string + previous and next word

Tags: javascript, ajax, string, match

I have a string like this: 
`This is my text`

When i search for a string like `is` i would like to get `This is my` as result, when i search for `This` i would like to get `This is` and for `text` the result should be `my text`

So i always try to find a string and get the searched string + the previous and next word if exists.

I know i can search with `mystring.match('search')` for a string, giving me the index but how i go further, maybe using `split`?

Maybe someone of you have an idea.

Thx for any help

ruven

Comment: What should happen with: `"...end of sentence. Start of new sentence." ` if you search for the word `Start`?

Comment: The result should be `sentence. Start of` as this is not a search for a whole text, only for a title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest the following approach, which uses a functional approach that allows you to pass both the word you're searching for and a string in which to search for that word:

```
function findWordAndNeighbours(needle, haystack) {
    if (!needle || !haystack) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var re = new RegExp('(\\S+[\\b\\s]' + needle + '[\\b\\s]\\S+)', 'i'),
            foundWords = haystack.match(re)[0].split(/\s+/),
            foundFragment = foundWords.join(' ');
        return foundFragment;
    }
}

var sentenceFragment = findWordAndNeighbours('test', 'This is a Test of a matching thing.');

console.log(sentenceFragment);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2GHJ5/).

**Edited** to update the above to include some error-catching, basically checking that there *are* some regex matches before trying to work with those matches:

```
function findWordAndNeighbours(needle, haystack) {
    if (!needle || !haystack) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var re = new RegExp('(\\S+[\\b\\s]' + needle + '[\\b\\s]\\S+)', 'i'),
            matches = haystack.match(re);
        if (matches) {
            // this is for if you wanted the individual words (as an array)
            var foundWords = haystack.match(re)[0].split(/\s+/),
                // this is to return the found sentence-fragment:
                foundFragment = foundWords.join(' ');
            return foundFragment;
        }
        else {
            /* this just follows the indexOf() pattern of, if you'd rather
               'return false' instead, that's entirely your call. */
            return -1;
        }
    }
}

var sentenceFragment = findWordAndNeighbours('test', 'This is a Test of a matching thing.');

console.log(sentenceFragment);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2GHJ5/2/).

**Edited** to correct for problems identified by OP in the comments (below):

> but this will not work if you search for This or thing, so the first or last word

The use of the `?` operands/special characters (meaning match the preceding character/group zero, or one, times) seems to correct for the problems in searching for the first, and last, word in the supplied string.

```
function findWordAndNeighbours(needle, haystack) {
    if (!needle || !haystack) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var re = new RegExp('((\\S+[\\b\\s]?)' + needle + '([\\b\\s]?\\S+))', 'i'),
            matches = haystack.match(re);
        console.log(matches);
        if (matches) {
            var foundWords = haystack.match(re)[0].split(/\s+/),
                foundFragment = foundWords.join(' ');
            return foundFragment;
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}

var sentenceFragment = findWordAndNeighbours('es', 'This is a Test of a matching thing.');

console.log(sentenceFragment);
```

However I was unable to find a neat way of searching for a substring from a given word, for example the `es` (from `test`, as in the example). The function returns the complete word (in this case `test`). If you want a naive correction for that behaviour, then I you could easily add in an `if (needle == matches[0]) {/* do something */}` check, and alter the behaviour as you think best. But I'm not entirely sure what the best way to handle that would be.

References:

- [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
- [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`RegExp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).
- [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).
- [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Comment: but this will not work if you search for This or thing, so the first or last word. but i got it working

Comment: ***D'oh!*** I *knew* I had something left on my to-do list! Sigh...but I'm glad you got it working! And, hopefully, my answer was of some help to you! =)

Comment: hm i tried to extend yours but when i would search for the first and last, i always get -1. Also when i try to search e.g. for `tes` (not the complete word) i get `a Test of a matching thing.` when i extend your regexp by `.*`. An idea how to change it, that it works correctly?

Comment: Hopefully the edited answer (the final code block) will be of better use to you. =)

Answer (score 1):

```
'asd d This is my text a'.match(/\s(\w*\sis\s\w*)\s/)[1] //=> "This is my"
```

Comment: Sorry but what word you are searching for? I think my javascript knowledge is not that good, so i do not understand this solution. Maybe you can explain it a bit?

Comment: This answer looks for white-space (`\s`) then a group of zero-or-more (`*`) alphanumeric characters (`\w`) another white-space then the literal `is` then a white-space and zero-or-more alphanumeric characters, then, after the group, another white-space. The `[1]` means to use the second array returned by the `match()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Here is working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/CbXPB/)

The code is in javascript

```
var str = "This is my text";

var strArr = str.split(" ");

var seacrhWord = "is";

for (i=0; i<strArr.length; i++)
   {
      if ( strArr[i] == seacrhWord)
      {
          var result = "";
          if (strArr[i-1] != null)
             result += strArr[i-1]

          result += " " + strArr[i];

          if (strArr[i+1] != null)
             result += " " + strArr[i+1];

          alert(result);
      }
  }
```

Comment: Ah cool, i understand this solution. Thank you. But isnt it a bit slow?

Comment: I think not because i am going on the array's values only ones.

Comment: but this only works if it is the same word and it is not case sensitive. when you search for `tex` it will not work.

Comment: Instead of `if ( strArr[i] == seacrhWord)` i use `if (strArr[i].indexOf(seacrhWord) >= 0)` so that i can search for wordparts.

Comment: This is fits your needs! nice solution! i am glade i was able to assist you :)

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution:

```
var input = 'Text? This is my simple text string where I use word TEXT a few times. Is it finding my text?'
var text = 'text';

input = input.toString();
text = text.toString().replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, '\\$&');

var preLength = 7;

var search = function () {
    if (position !== -1) {
        var sliceStart = (position - preLength) >= 0 ? position - preLength : 0;
        var sliceEnd = position + text.length + preLength;

        var matchedText = input.slice(sliceStart, sliceEnd).trim();

        var preText = ((position - preLength) >= 0) && !result.length ? '...' : '';
        var postText = input.slice(sliceEnd).trim().length > 0 ? '...' : '';

        result = result + preText + matchedText + postText;

        input = input.slice(sliceEnd);
        lowercaseInput = lowercaseInput.slice(sliceEnd);

        position = lowercaseInput.search(lowercaseText);
    }
}

var lowercaseInput = input.toLowerCase();
var lowercaseText = text.toLowerCase();

var result = '';
var position = lowercaseInput.search(lowercaseText);

while (position !== -1) {
    search();
}

console.log(result);
```

This looks up for a searched text and returns a result with all matches.

http://jsfiddle.net/bqwn1whq/

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion  For "this i" etc you can use regex , 3 or 4 case
for start with ^this ?  but this search is unhealty if not be careful. space and unmatching terms can create problem hard to match
this i*. for substring match match(/yoursearchterm/[A-Za-z0-9_-]*/i) 
if not match then you use substring of yoursearchterm like
yoursearchterm.substring(0,yoursearchterm.length-1)
in for loop try to make -1 to -i for similarity ,

Full Text search  or like expression in sql . 
For better result the Regex for sql may help you but both of them {like and regex not very fast} .for matching by similarity 
like 
apple is your data
and the appla or app or appl or eppl is your search them
you can make them find via
the levenstein . in php http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php
for a substring or long sentenced you can use the way that 
split {or explode } the data by space
. ie here I am 
and your data splitted 3 
here I am 
both of them you can apply the lev or like regex 
matching is successfull but you have to think of performance your query